# How to get the ObjectId value from MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework-2.0, jackson, jongo

I'm using `Jongo` with `Play framework 2`, java. I added some data into my `MongoDB`.

```js
{"_id" : ObjectId("538dafffbf6b562617252178"), ... }
```

However, when I fetched the `ObjectId` from the database, it gave me like:

`de.undercouch.bson4jackson.types.ObjectId@484431ff` instead of `538dafffbf6b562617252178`. I don't quite understand how can I get the `ObjectId` value. My class is defined as following:

```java
public class Product {
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    protected String id;
    ...
    public Product() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

In order to fetch the data, I simply use `find()` function provided by `Jongo` as following:

```java
public static Iterable<Product> findAll(){
    return products().find().as(Product.class);
}
```

Comment: Did you try fetching it using the key value ie cursor.get("_id").valueOf() ?

Comment: @AppleBud I used `find()` method to fetch the data. Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id field annotated with @JsonProperty("_id") just means that your product documents have custom ids (ie. setted by user eg: 1234, 5678, ...)

You should annotate id field with both @Id and @ObjectId annotations to tell Jongo to handle id field as a real ObjectId managed by MongoDB.

```
public class Product {

@org.jongo.marshall.jackson.oid.Id
@org.jongo.marshall.jackson.oid.ObjectId
protected String id;
...
  public Product() {
  }
}
```

During deserialization, a string representation of ObjectId will be setted into Product instances

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried what you mentioned above, however, it gave me `Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid ObjectId [de.undercouch.bson4jackson.types.ObjectId@6e07e6fc] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->models.Product["_id"])]]`

Comment: You should open an issue https://github.com/bguerout/jongo/issues and provide the full stack trace. This question will be updated later with what we have found.

Answer (score 1):

Your ObjectId is of type de.undercouch.bson4jackson.types.ObjectId. By looking at the [source](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson/blob/master/src/main/java/de/undercouch/bson4jackson/types/ObjectId.java) you can see that there isn't a `toString` method defined on that class, so the default `toString` implementation is used instead.

MongoDB's [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#the-id-field) is actually 12-bit BSON type that's constructed using:

> ```
> a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> a 3-byte machine identifier,
> a 2-byte process id, and
> a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
> ```

The class your are using is built a little bit different - it's internally stored as 3 integers. It has public `getTime`, `getMachine` and `getInc` methods so you can create your own using those values. Something like this will probably get you what you want:

```
(id.getTime() + id.getMachine() + ide.GetInc()).toHexString()
```